# About signed measure induced by a continuous function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\alpha:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function and $\mu$ be a signed measure on $X$. Also suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are equipped with the Borel $\sigma-$algebra. $\alpha$ then induces a signed measure $\nu$ on $Y$: for every measurable set $E$ of $Y$,
$$\nu(E):=\mu(\alpha^{-1}(E))$$
$\nu$ can be decomposed into two positive measures: $\nu=\nu^+-\nu^-$. Is it true that
$$\nu^+=\mu^+\circ\alpha^{-1}, \nu^-=\mu^-\circ \alpha^{-1}?$$
By the Jordan decomposition theorem, it suffices to show that $\mu^+\circ\alpha^{-1}$ and $\mu^-\circ \alpha^{-1}$ are two mutually singular measures, but I am not sure how to do it. I am in particular interested in the case that $X,Y$ are locally compact Hausdorff or even compact Hausdorff.

Background: I want to know the answer for the above question because I want to prove that for every $g\in L^1(\nu)$,
$$\int_X g\circ \alpha \, d\mu=\int_Yg \, d(\mu\circ \alpha^{-1})$$
which appears in the paper "The Riesz Representation Theorem Revisited" written by Hartig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $X=Y=\mathbb R$ and set $\mu^+(A) = 2 \int_0^\infty \chi_A(x) e^{-x^2} \,dx$ and $\mu^-(A) = \int_{-\infty}^0 \chi_A(x) e^{-x^2} \,dx$ with $\chi_A$ being the indicator function of $A.$ (The factor $e^{-x^2}$ is used primarily to make the measures finite.) Then taking $\alpha(x)=|x|$ we have $\mu^+\circ\alpha^{-1} = 2 \mu^-\circ\alpha^{-1}.$

Therefore, setting $\mu=\mu^+-\mu^-$ and $\nu = \mu\circ\alpha^{-1}$ we get
$$
\nu 
= \mu^+\circ\alpha^{-1} - \mu^-\circ\alpha^{-1}
= 2\mu^-\circ\alpha^{-1} - \mu^-\circ\alpha^{-1}
= \mu^-\circ\alpha^{-1},
$$
which is a positive measure. This implies that $\nu^+=\nu$ and $\nu^-=0.$

Thus we cannot have $\nu^+=\mu^+\circ\alpha^{-1}$ and $\nu^-=\mu^-\circ\alpha^{-1}.$

Comment: Nice! I guess a lot of counterexamples can be constructed by using the absolute value function.

Comment: @Rmal. Or other non-injective functions.